# Ajax unique validation on update user information form Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii2

Now, i have an update form with three inputs - username, email and password. Everything is ok except the case when i try to update only the password.
For example: Username and email of the user have to stay the same and only the password must be changed. And here what is happening:[image: the result of performing this action]

In this case i am trying to update only the password of the user.
Controller actionUpdate:

```
public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $model = new UpdateForm();
        $id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $user = $this->findModel($id);

        //default values
        $model->username = $user->username;
        $model->email = $user->email;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['UpdateForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['UpdateForm'];

            if($model->validate())
            {

                $user->username = $model->username;
                $user->email = $model->email;
                $user->password = md5($model->password);

                $user->update();

                $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $user->id]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

UpdateForm model rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email', 'password', 'username'], 'required'],
            [['email', 'password', 'username'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['username', 'password', 'email'], 'trim'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            [[ 'email', 'username'], 'unique',
                                     'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'username'],
                                     'message' => 'The combination of username and password is already taken'],
        ];
    }
```

Appreciating every advice! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I thing you want scenarios see this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Try using save()  instead of update()

```
  if (isset($_POST['UpdateForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['UpdateForm'];

        if($model->validate())
        {

            $user->username = $model->username;
            $user->email = $model->email;
            $user->password = md5($model->password);

            $user->save();

            $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $user->id]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried. Without result.

Comment: try don'y assigning the $user->username = $model->username;             $user->email = $model->email; when not needed

Comment: Did not work that way also. I am not really familiar whit this scenario thing will read for it first and if i got success i will inform you :D